# How to set same value for all the textboxes in an unordered list in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

Suppose i have 5 textboxes in a list.I enter text input in the first text box and click send. Now i want the input value entered to be showed in all the other textboxes in the list.

Following is my html code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
        <script src="./scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./scripts/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="chatApp">
        <div ng-controller="chatController">
            <ul>    
                <li ng-repeat="chat in chats">
                    <input type="text"/>
                    <button ng-click="sendChat()">Send</button>
                    <button ng-click="deleteChat($index)">Delete</button>
                </li>
            </ul>   
            <button ng-click="addChat()">Click me to add</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Following is my angular code:-

```
var app=angular.module('chatApp',[]);

app.controller('chatController',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.chats=[];
    $scope.addChat = function() {
        if($scope.chats.length<10)
        {
            $scope.chats.push({name:''});
        }
     }
    $scope.deleteChat=function(index){
        $scope.chats.splice(index,1);
    }
    $scope.sendChat=function(data){

    }

}]);
```

I have a sendChat function where i was thinking to put the code.

Comment: why was this downvoted? anything wrong in my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add model in your  input field

```
<input type="text" ng-model="chat.msg"/>
```

Then pass the selected msg

```
<button ng-click="sendChat(chat)">Send</button>
```

Then assign msg in other textboxes

```
$scope.sendChat = function(data) {
    $scope.chats.map(function(x) {
        x.msg = data.msg;
    })
}
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/7L706pbr/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: sorry bro! i actually tried to upvote and clicked downvote by mistake. if you can edit your answer, i will upvote again